# Insert from one Oracle table into another with where condition

Tags: oracle, insert, where-clause

I want to insert data from one table into another e.g. i have a table with only one column which is 'timekey' and i want to add this timekey to another table where timekey is null. I have used this query but it is not working.

```
insert into files_recon_3 (timekey) 
(select timekey from batch_DT)
where exists
(
select timekey from files_recon_3 where timekey is null
);
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to do this work. Thanks

Comment: I guess you have to use an update statement..

Comment: i have also used update statement it is updating all the values but i dont want that i just want to add the values where timekey is null.

Comment: Can u please post your update statement also?

Comment: update files_recon_3 set (timekey) = (select timekey from batch_DT) where exists  (select timekey from files_recon_3 where timekey is null);

Comment: Using simple update clause solved my problem :)
update files_recon_3 set timekey = (select timekey from batch_DT)   where timekey is null;

Comment: "*not working*" is not a valid Oracle error message.

Comment: it is not an error message its just a message in simple english that it is not working :P

Comment: hint hint: if someone says *'"not working" is not a valid Oracle error message'*, that means you haven't provided enough information. You need to specify what results you expected, and what results you actually see.

Comment: Well i will be careful in the future. In my case it was not giving any error it was running successfully but it was not doing the task i wanted it to do, it was just adding new rows.